# Tiered? structure of complex Zend Framework models/objects

Tags: oop, zend-framework

What is the best way to store complex models in ZF?  In the example below, should each attribute be a separate model entirely, or should the item be a multi dimensional array (as shown below)?

```
object(Application_Model_Item)#79 (4) {
  ["_id":protected] => int(45)
  ["_name":protected] => string(5) "Bolts"
  ["_description":protected] => NULL
  ["_attributes":protected] => array(2) {
    [0] => array(2) {
      ["id"] => string(1) "3"
      ["name"] => string(4) "Size"
    }
    [1] => array(2) {
      ["id"] => string(1) "4"
      ["name"] => string(6) "Length"
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any specific ORM requirements? Would a suggestion detailing Doctrine ORM be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your use case:

**Indexing by ID or Position:**

- If you would like speed when accessing a particular attribute, then index the attributes by their IDs instead of their index position.
- If you would like to keep an order, then order them by index position and a position offset amount.

**Independent Table Vs Local Array:**

- If the attributes are duplicated in multiple items, then have them as their own table, and reference the attributes to that table.
- If the attributes are not refenced and are unique to each item, then using them as serialise-able arrays (for storage) is adequate than needing them to be their own table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really should take a look at doctrine it's just I'm too lazy to learn a new language. I've also heard doctrine can become quite resource intensive so I was planning on coding the mappers myself (in php).

Comment: No worries, hope I helped :-)

Doctrine is actually fairly simple to learn, I moved to it after my own ORM was getting a bit too legacy. It is quite resource intensive and difficult to debug at times, but I don't regret the move as the downfalls are entirely reasonable as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of _attributes i would use array of objects. 
So it attributes would be an array of new model Attribute()

I make a class for every business model entity

```
["_attributes":protected] => array(2) {
    [0] => Object(Model_Attribute) {}
    [1] => Object(Model_Attribute) {}
}

class Model_Attribute {
  protected $id;
  public function getId();
  public function setId($id);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I suggest you look at Doctrine ORM **2.0** since it can support the design from the above.
Look at this page, it may give you a clue:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/association-mapping/en